# Is there an iOS app that measures/reports the battery charging current?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, battery, charging

I suspect my fake lightening cable charge my iPhone 5 much slower than my original lightening cable on the same charger. Is there an app that will display the current battery draw/charging current and also plot it over time?

Answer (score 1):

The battery doctor HD app by KS moblie tells me the charging current for my iPad 2.  However the battery doctor app for iPhone 4s does not appear to give this information.

Answer (score 1):

there is a new app on the Apple store - Amperes. It shows the charging rate of your iPad/ iPhone.

FREE version: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amperes-l/id1253789580?mt=8

$0.99 version:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amperes/id1245475416?mt=8

Comment: It's helpful if you provide a link to the referenced App so readers don't have to go searching for it.

Comment: Added the links.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, I don't think there is an app that can show the charger current. But there is a few app that can record your charging time and charging statistics. Try to search something like "battery doctor" or "battery" in AppStore. You can then compare the fake and the real one's charging time.

Answer (score 0):

Battery box or battery health. You could also contact Apple for a diagnostics test (they will text or email it to your iDevice)

Comment: Can you tell us more about how the diagnostics test addresses the question?

BTW, http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134482/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-amp-levels-while-charging-my-iphone is a dupe of this question, with some good answers.

Answer (score -2):

download battery charging speedometer

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review